# Materialize CSS returns previously selected value from the EventListener on a Select

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const selects = document.querySelector("select");
  const instances = M.FormSelect.init(selects, {});
  const selectOption = document.querySelector("#option-select");
    
  selectOption.addEventListener("change", function () {
    const instance = M.FormSelect.getInstance(selectOption);
    const selectedValues = instance.getSelectedValues();
    console.log(selectedValues[0]);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<select id="option-select">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using select of Materialize CSS to return the selected value.

1. First selection returns the undefined
2. Second selection returns the first selection
3. Third selections returns the second and so.....

[Image of output from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbWdM.png)

The UI is working fine, but I JS is exhibiting the above unusual behaviour. Can anybody explain what's going on here. I'm a bit stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a bug is in Materialize CSS. There are some workarounds online but none are clean.

The bug has been fixed in the Alpha version at the time of writing so in the end I decided to update stylesheet and script tags to match the same.

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const selects = document.querySelector("select");
    const instances = M.FormSelect.init(selects, {});
  });

  const selectOption = document.querySelector("#option-select");    
  selectOption.addEventListener("change", function () {
    const instance = M.FormSelect.getInstance(selectOption);
    const selectedValues = instance.getSelectedValues();
    console.log(selectedValues[0]);
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0/dist/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="input-field col s12">
<select id="option-select">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0/dist/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```